# puppet erb dynamic content

Tags: ruby, puppet, erb

site.pp

```
class httpd_conf_files ($repos) {
    ensure_packages(['httpd'], {'ensure' => 'present'})
    $repos.each |String $repo| {
    file {"/etc/httpd/conf.d/${repo}_repo1.conf":
                                  ensure  => file,
                                  mode    => '0644',
                                      content => template('deploy/repos.erb'),
          }
      }
}
```

nodes.pp

```
node 'repo-web-c010' {
                  class { httpd_conf_files:
                           repos => ['centos','ubuntu'],
                  }
}
```

However, both files centos_repo1.conf and ubuntu_repo1.conf have the same content.

repos.erb

```
    <% @repos.each do |rep|
    if rep == "centos"
        $x      = "/opt/repos/yum/"+rep
                 $_repo  = rep
         else
                 $x      = "/opt/repos/"+rep
                 $_repo  = rep
         end

    end -%>
    Alias /<%=$_repo%> <%=$x%>
    DocumentRoot  <%=$x%>
    IndexOptions NameWidth=* +SuppressDescription
    <Directory <%=$x%>>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog logs/<%=$_repo%>_repo1_error.log
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog logs/<%=$_repo%>_repo1_access.log combined
```

Can someone enlighten me what's wrong?

Comment: I'm not familiar with how your template is being parsed but is it possible that the `@repos.each` block is being run on all repos then, with the last assigned values, parsing the template? If you reverse the order of your :repos in `notes.pp` do both files then have _centos_ info? Do you get access a variable containing the current $repo? HTH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic in your ERB template, as hinted at in a comment, is invalid.

Because you loop through the `@repos` array and set `$x` and `$_repo` on each iteration, those variables always take their values from the last iteration of that loop. This is why you always end up with the same generated content.

The template could be changed to this:

```
<% if @repo == "centos"
     x = "/opt/repos/yum/" + @repo
     _repo = @repo
   else
     x = "/opt/repos/" + @repo
     _repo = @repo
   end -%>
Alias /<%= _repo %> <%= x %>
DocumentRoot  <%= x %>
IndexOptions NameWidth=* +SuppressDescription
<Directory <%= x %>>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

ErrorLog logs/<%= _repo %>_repo1_error.log
LogLevel warn

CustomLog logs/<%= _repo %>_repo1_access.log combined
```

Notice that I also changed your variables `$x` and `$_repo` because the dollar sign denotes global variables in Ruby, and global variables are probably not what you want there.

It would be better still if you moved the conditional logic from your ERB template into your Puppet manifest.

Finally, you really need to fix up your indentation because it is very hard to read as you have it.

Comment: Thanks Alex, 

I do have now a better  understanding of  how to work with erb templates  !

Comment: @johnnybravo, That's great and don't forget to accept the answer if you're satisfied that it fixed your issue.